# Accessing Data Values With "$" Sign In Assembly

Tags: assembly, msp430

I want to know how I can access the data stored in these variables...but I have no idea with N0$ for example stands for and how to extract the data from there into a register, for example.

```
N0$:    .byte   DASH,DASH,DASH,DASH,DASH,END    ; 0
N1$:    .byte   DOT,DASH,DASH,DASH,DASH,END     ; 1
N2$:    .byte   DOT,DOT,DASH,DASH,DASH,END      ; 2
N3$:    .byte   DOT,DOT,DOT,DASH,DASH,END       ; 3
N4$:    .byte   DOT,DOT,DOT,DOT,DASH,END        ; 4
N5$:    .byte   DOT,DOT,DOT,DOT,DOT,END         ; 5
N6$:    .byte   DASH,DOT,DOT,DOT,DOT,END        ; 6
N7$:    .byte   DASH,DASH,DOT,DOT,DOT,END       ; 7
N8$:    .byte   DASH,DASH,DASH,DOT,DOT,END      ; 8
N9$:    .byte   DASH,DASH,DASH,DASH,DOT,END     ; 9

A$:     .byte   DOT,DASH,END                    ; A
B$:     .byte   DASH,DOT,DOT,DOT,END            ; B
C$:     .byte   DASH,DOT,DASH,DOT,END           ; C
D$:     .byte   DASH,DOT,DOT,END                ; D
E$:     .byte   DOT,END                         ; E
F$:     .byte   DOT,DOT,DASH,DOT,END            ; F
G$:     .byte   DASH,DASH,DOT,END               ; G
H$:     .byte   DOT,DOT,DOT,DOT,END             ; H
I$:     .byte   DOT,DOT,END                     ; I
J$:     .byte   DOT,DASH,DASH,DASH,END          ; J
K$:     .byte   DASH,DOT,DASH,END               ; K
L$:     .byte   DOT,DASH,DOT,DOT,END            ; L
M$:     .byte   DASH,DASH,END                   ; M
N$:     .byte   DASH,DOT,END                    ; N
O$      .byte   DASH,DASH,DASH,END              ; O
P$:     .byte   DOT,DASH,DASH,DOT,END           ; P
Q$:     .byte   DASH,DASH,DOT,DASH,END          ; Q
R$:     .byte   DOT,DASH,DOT,END                ; R
S$:     .byte   DOT,DOT,DOT,END                 ; S
T$:     .byte   DASH,END                        ; T
U$:     .byte   DOT,DOT,DASH,END                ; U
V$:     .byte   DOT,DOT,DOT,DASH,END            ; V
W$:     .byte   DOT,DASH,DASH,END               ; W
X$:     .byte   DASH,DOT,DOT,DASH,END           ; X
Y$:     .byte   DASH,DOT,DASH,DASH,END          ; Y
Z$:     .byte   DASH,DASH,DOT,DOT,END           ; Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know your processor, or Assembly compiler but from what i've learned.

in tasm:

rename the variables to something easier N0$ would be like

```
  array1    db     'value1','value2','$'
```

then to write that to screen using tasm

```
    mov ax,09h
    mov dx, offset array1
    int 21h
```

Sorry if it's not what you're looking for.